# Python script doesn't execute bash commands in cron job

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, cron

I have written Python script which I want to execute everyday on my server (Cent OS). I need to execute some bash commands directly from my Python script. Everything works fine when I run the script directly from terminal, but bash commands are not executed when cron job executes the script, although the script does the rest of it is job (inserting to database etc).

My crontab looks as follows:

```
00 20 * * 1-5 /home/skanydok/script.sh
```

script.sh contains

```
#!/bin/bash

python /home/skanydok/serverBarcodeScanner.py
```

I have several methods which are meant to move, copy or delete files from server, an example method looks as follows:

```
def copyBackup():
cmd = "cp -r SKANY_DOKUMENTOW_" + str(now)[:10] + '_' + str(random) + " ./backupy"
call(cmd.split(" "))
```

Also I use this code to save all output from method print to a log file:

```
class Logger(object):  
def __init__(self):
    self.terminal = sys.stdout
    self.log = open("./backupy/log.txt", "a")

def write(self, message):
    self.terminal.write(message)
    self.log.write(message)


sys.stdout = Logger()
```

The log.txt file is not created, all methods which are supposed to execute commands like cp, mv, rm etc. does not work, although they work fine when executing script on server with:

```
python /home/skanydok/serverBarcodeScanner.py
```

I think there must be something in the water with cron jobs, all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path of `python`? E.g `/usr/bin/python /home/skanydok ...`

Comment: as @Farhan.K mentioned above, try using absolute path of `python` or load user's bash profile instead of `#!/bin/bash` like `. ~/.bash_profile` . Also don't forget to use absolute paths whenever we are referring a path inside script or make sure to use `cd` and `pwd` checks inside to make sure the script is running in the required path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with cronjobs *per se*, but with the fact that your script uses relative path. Relative path are resolved against the "current working directory", which is not the same when you run the script manually from your home directory and when it's run by cron. The solution is, obviously, to only use absolute path in your script. You can harcode them in the python script itself if they are not supposed to change (which seems to be the case here) or use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` in your python script to get the script's directory path.